# Weird setspace-standalone interaction

Tags: standalone, setspace

Say I am dividing my thesis into chapter files using `standalone`.

My `chp.tex` file is:

```
\documentclass[class=report, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pkgs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
bla bla bla\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: chp.tex file]

And then I load this file from the `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{report}    
\usepackage{pkgs}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\input{chp}
\end{document}
```

[image: main.tex file]

These are the only packages I am loading from the `pkgs.sty` file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pkgs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

---

My understanding is that `\doublespacing` (from `setspace`) should not affect tables and footnotes -- which it does for `main.tex`, but not for `chp.tex`, as you can see from the pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this. I need to pass the `float` option to the `standalone` documentclass, otherwise I guess standalone does some trickery to make floats working.

```
- \documentclass[class=report, crop=false]{standalone}
+ \documentclass[class=report, crop=false, float]{standalone}
```